# jquery tokeninput with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, tokenize, jquery-tokeninput

I am using Jquery Tokeninput in my project to display some numbers in a textarea. I have a hidden input field in which I save the JSON string containing the numbers.
The JSON looks like

```
patents = [{"id":"AT02708872"},{"id":"DE60232348"},{"id":"EP02708872"},{"id":"SE0101087"},{"id":"SE0200504"}]
```

in my view the hidden input is

```
  <input id="appln_nrs" type="hidden" value="{{ patents }}" />
```

In the same view I pass the value of this input to my JQuery Tokeninput as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var patents = $("#appln_nrs").val();
        //var patents = [{id:"ABC"},{id:"DEF"}];
        $("#patents").tokenInput("", {
            theme:"facebook",
            prePopulate: patents
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is the JSON contains only 5 entries with id and its value, but when I am on the view it display something like this in the textarea[image]

But when I pass some hard coded JSON to patents variable it is displayed properly.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit

When I use in my javascript like

```
 var patents = {{ patents }};
```

it gives me the following syntax error

```
  SyntaxError: invalid property id
  [Break On This Error]     

  var patents = [{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;AT.02708872.T&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;...
```

Comment: Why are you using a hidden field? Can you post the html of the generated hidden field?

Comment: The generated hidden input field is <input id="appln_nrs" type="hidden" value="[{"id":"AT02708872"},{"id":"DE60232348"},{"id":"EP02708872"},{"id":"SE0101087"},{"id":"SE0200504"}]">

Comment: i am using hidden input field to pass the patents from php to my Jquery

Comment: You have to ask twig not to escape your variable using |raw. Edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don´t use a hidden field. Just do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var patents = {{patents|raw}};
        //var patents = [{id:"ABC"},{id:"DEF"}];
        $("#patents").tokenInput("", {
            theme:"facebook",
            prePopulate: patents
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now it displays nothing in the textarea

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a semicolon after '{{patents}}'. Now fixed

Comment: when I use var patents = {{patents}}; and alert(patents).. its says function Array() {
    [native code]
}

Comment: Can you post the code of the generated html for this script? Also notice that in the code that works (var patents = [{id:"ABC"},{id:"DEF"}];) id is not quoted. Maybe you have to change that when generating the json

Comment: actually I am getting Array in patents variable in my view

Comment: Sorry. When I echo patents in add view it shows the correct JSON, but when i display it in JS like var patents = {{ patents }} it shows nothing. I will edit my question